# Python multiple loops

Tags: python

`A = [[[1,2,3],[4]],[[1,4],[2,3]]]`

Here I want to find lists in A which sum of all sublists in list not grater than 5.

Which the result should be `[[1,4],[2,3]]`

I tried a long time to solve this problem in python. But I still can't figure out the right solution, which I stuck at loop out multiple loops. My code as follows, but its obviously wrong, how to correct it?

```
A = [[[1,2,3],[4]],[[1,4],[2,3]]]
z = []
for l in A:
    for list in l:
        sum = 0
        while sum < 5:
            for i in list:
                sum+=i
        else:
            break
    else:
        z.append(l)
print z
```

Asking for help~

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: Your more likely to get help if you post some code, preferably a [mcve]. That shows us that you've tried to solve this problem yourself, and we can point out why your code doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: First of all the premise of this question is not very clear. What kind of input do you expect?  Are the lists nested to only 3 levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution which you can think of would be like this -

```
A = [[[1,2,3],[4]],[[1,4],[2,3]]]

r = []   # this will be our result

for list in A:  # Iterate through each item in A
    f = True    # This is a flag we set for a favorable sublist
    for item in list:  # Here we iterate through each list in the sublist
        if sum(item) > 5:  # If the sum is greater than 5 in any of them, set flag to false
            f = False
    if f:       # If the flag is set, it means this is a favorable sublist
        r.append(list)

print r
```

But I'm assuming the nesting level would be the same. http://ideone.com/hhr9uq

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what  I am looking for.

Comment: @GauravOjha, Instead of the boolean `f` you can use a [*Else Clauses on Loop Statements*](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html#else-clauses-on-loop-statements) to do exactly the same thing. Please have a look at the link.

Comment: Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

Simplification of @KindStranger method in a one-liner:

```
>> [sub for x in A for sub in x if max(sum(sub) for sub in x) <= 5]
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your problem:

```
>>> for alist in A:
...     if max(sum(sublist) for sublist in alist) <= 5:
...         print(alist)
...
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The one with `all()`

```
[t for item in A for t in item if all(sum(t)<=5 for t in item)]
```